# How to extract the text through a href using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, getattribute

I looked on every Posts but didnt get the solution i want.

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*/section/main/div/div[3]/article/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/a")
pic = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*/section/main/div/div[3]/article/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/a").get(title)
print(title)
```

Thats my Code just now but I Need exactly this:

```html
<a href="/p/BrDudIUBuNr/"><div class="eLAPa"><div class="KL4Bh"><img class="FFVAD" decoding="auto" sizes="281.671875px" srcset="https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/38a5fdde34937b2b3e4e600da56c46b5/5C0D05B3/t51.2885-15/e15/s150x150/46276509_388170972011907_7609813800358803282_n.jpg 150w,https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/74b222ca252a488bb5eb110347283c3b/5C0CB7F9/t51.2885-15/e15/s240x240/46276509_388170972011907_7609813800358803282_n.jpg 240w,https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/af2eff79d9c38b0f97a763041e3a99e5/5C0D10C3/t51.2885-15/e15/s320x320/46276509_388170972011907_7609813800358803282_n.jpg 320w,https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/bad123f6264636de35489b7d8dc2cbed/5C0CC199/t51.2885-15/e15/s480x480/46276509_388170972011907_7609813800358803282_n.jpg 480w,https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/93a4e36addf453f754e4caba706fe93a/5C0CC82C/t51.2885-15/e15/s640x640/46276509_388170972011907_7609813800358803282_n.jpg 640w" src="https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/93a4e36addf453f754e4caba706fe93a/5C0CC82C/t51.2885-15/e15/s640x640/46276509_388170972011907_7609813800358803282_n.jpg" style=""></div><div class="_9AhH0"></div></div><div class="u7YqG"><div class="Byj2F"><span class="glyphsSpriteVideo_large u-__7" aria-label="Video"></span></div></div></a>
```

a href and then Comes a link which i need

Comment: Your question title states that you want the link.text but in your question body you posted that you need the HTML... which is it? Please update your code because right now it does nothing and won't compile.

Comment: THATS THE PROBLEM

Comment: You didn't answer any of my questions or update your question with the info requested. If you want help, you need to do both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract the *text* **Video** you can use either of the following solutions:

- `css_selector`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[href='/p/BrDudIUBuNr/'] span.glyphsSpriteVideo_large").get_attribute("aria-label")
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='/p/BrDudIUBuNr/']//span[contains(@class,'glyphsSpriteVideo_large')]").get_attribute("aria-label")
  ```